# In Django, by model get the automatic id field set to null=True and I get IntegrityError: "may not be null"

Tags: django, django-models

I've been trying to reset my database and figure out why this is happening, but for some reason I'm getting this error:

```
IntegrityError: main_funding_rounds_investments.investment_id may not be NULL
```

I can't figure out how or why the automatic id field would be null? If anyone has ideas I would greatly appreciate it!

When i check the db with inspectdb, I get the following:

```
class MainFundingRoundsInvestments(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    funding_rounds_id = models.IntegerField()
    investment_id = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'main_funding_rounds_investments'
```

and

```
class MainInvestment(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'main_investment'
```

Here are my models:

```
#funding rounds
class funding_rounds(models.Model):
    funded_day = models.IntegerField(null=True)
investments = models.ManyToManyField("Investment")

class Investment(models.Model):
    company = models.ManyToManyField("Company", null=True, related_name     ="Investments_company")
    financial_org = models.ManyToManyField("Financial_org", null=True, related_name ="Investments_financial_org")
    person = models.ManyToManyField("Person", null=True, related_name ="Investments_person")
```

This is where I create the objects:

```
def save_dict_to_db_R(model_class ,dicta):

testCo = model_class()

for key,value in dicta.items():
    try:
        field = model_class._meta.get_field(key)

        if isinstance(field, models.ManyToManyField):
            continue
        else:
            if model_class._meta.get_field(key):
                print("i == something:" + key + " ")
                setattr(testCo, key, value)
    except FieldDoesNotExist:
        continue

testCo.save(

for field in model_class._meta.many_to_many:
    if field.name in dicta and hasattr(dicta[field.name], 'append'):
        for obj in dicta[field.name]:
            rel_instance = save_dict_to_db_R(field.rel.to, obj)
            getattr(testCo, field.name).add(rel_instance)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why have you set the primary key field manually? Unless you need to call the field something different from `id`, or give it different attributes, you should just leave it out of the model and let Django add it automatically.

Your immediate problem is that you've used IntegerField instead of AutoField, but if you removed your definition automatically that would be done for you.

Comment: Hi, the first model definition in my question is not my model, it's what I get when running "manage.py inspectdb". I am letting Django add 'id' automatically. I'm wondering why it's not AutoField though if it is supposed to be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

Comment: It is set automatically by Django. I think the AutoField is actually an IntegerField? Docs: [Primary Key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key)

Comment: Primary keys added by Django are represented as Integers in the database, yes. `AutoField` is just Python wrapper that represents the auto incrementing field when working with Django models. Additionally, [`inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) can't guess what wrappers you want on the model fields so it uses `IntegerField` for PK since that is what the database looks like.